# Java - Structuring the flow of data in GUI from input to output

Tags: java, event-handling, structure

I'm putting together a GUI with a couple of panels.
In one panel there are components for the user to input various parameters. 
In another panel, there are buttons and a place to output a plot based on data
generated using the user inputs.

I have all of the various pieces working independently now I'd just like them to 
talk to each other!!

When i hit one button, I would like to take all of user inputs and combine them to
generate a data set and plot it.
Another button then to write this same data to a file.

I have code to implement all the components individually, code to write data to 
a file and code to generate a plot from data.  All of which works fine.

I thought that I could use the Action/ChangeEvents to take the parameters and
assign them to an ArrayList. Then use this arraylist to generate the data.
I'm finding it difficult to plan an approach to tackling this.

Currently I'm using get set methods in the event handlers to set parameter levels for
a particular instance of the array list, I would like to pass this instance into another class to generate the data but don't know how to make it accessible.

I hope I have provided enought information here. If anyone has any 
thoughts on this they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. It might be stupid to ask but can't you write a getter in the object that holds the arraylist to retrieve it?

Comment: No that's an excellent question and i think the crux of my problem. Event handlers in the InputPanel class use set Methods from a class which I've called TestList to set the parameters.  I have done this using an instance of the TestList class we'll call 'X'. Now, I wrote a getList() method to return this completed ArrayList but would like to call that getList() method, for that particular (X) instance in a different class altogether.  Perhaps I am heading in the wrong direction with this approach

Comment: Perhaps to clarify, TestList contains get set methods for defining the ArrayList which holds the parameters taken from user input, necessary to create data.  It also has a getList() method to return the completed list.  The InputPanel class creates the panel where the user inputs parameters, the set methods from the TestList class are used in eventhandlers to assign the parameters to the ArrayList.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see what you're trying to do... What stops you from calling the method from another class? Does the other class not "know" it gets a TestList instance specifically, and therefore does it not "know" the getList method is there?

Comment: Precisely, and I'm afraid I don't know how to make that instance (and method) accessible to another class.  I've been tinkering about with final and static but if that is the answer, I haven't found out how to apply them appropriately

Comment: What you really need is an interface. Make the other class expect an instance that implements the interface. That way the method will be accessible, when you define it in the interface.

Comment: That's great, thank you for being so generous with your time and thoughts.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a structured way to tackle your issue is to apply the MVC pattern. Here is what I think a seminal article about Model-View-Controller (MVC) using Java.

[Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html) by Robert Eckstein,

and here is [another sample code](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html).

As for taking the parameters from one panel and pass them on to the other panel, you can use the Command Pattern. What the pattern does is basically encapsulate all the information needed for a method to perform (an instance of a class, parameters, etc.) into one Command. This Command then can be passed around in the application, simplifying the way you execute the method.

A good book about Design Patterns, by the way, that I really love is [Head First Design Pattern](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do).

EDIT:
I'd just like to add some links discussing about MVC and some other GUI architectures that I find useful:

- [GUI Architectures by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)
- [Build your own Composite Application Block series: UI Architechtures, Patterns and WinForm Examples](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents)
- [MVVM vs MVP vs MVC: The differences](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained)

Comment: 2 minor points.  1) Answers can be edited. (So no need to add the comment.) 2) It is considered better to amalgamate links with the link description.  E.G. [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) - to do this, use the little 'chain' icon at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: thanks for the tips Andrew! I'm new so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good case of application of MVC pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Another good resource would be this book's second chapter:
[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1334437965&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this. Putting a name on what I'm aiming for will make seeking information a lot easier.

Comment: No worries, can you flag this as answer to your question, please